# NSUrlCache disk limit?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, afnetworking, nsurlcache

I am trying to store a large array of images on the server and use `AFNetworking`'s image caching feature which takes advantage of `NSUrlCache`, so that the app wouldn't need to hit the server all the time and would even work while offline.

It is important that the images never expire and stay cached forever, so I was wondering if there is a disk limit to how much space the cache can take up to. (For example the cache may expire old images when it hits the limit) thank you!

Answer (score 4):

To check current limit:

```
 NSLog(@"Disk Limit: %u bytes and converted to MB: %u", [NSURLCache sharedURLCache].diskCapacity, [NSURLCache sharedURLCache].diskCapacity/1024/1024);
 NSLog(@"Memory Limit: %u bytes and converted to MB: %u", [NSURLCache sharedURLCache].memoryCapacity, [NSURLCache sharedURLCache].memoryCapacity/1024/1024);
```

Create bigger cache use:

```
- (id)initWithMemoryCapacity:(NSUInteger)memoryCapacity diskCapacity:(NSUInteger)diskCapacity diskPath:(NSString *)path
```

NSURLRequest handles cache options using NSURLRequestCachePolicy property.